# Index matching with the same unique identifier to pull through only unique values

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a table of the following format:

[image: Original form]

I would like to be able to pull through a unique value for each case of the ID appearing in a second table. E.g. I would like the following to be achieved:

[image: Desired format post index match]

I know that the number of IDs in the original table will be equal to that in the second set.

I beleive the following formula can be adjusted to pull out only unique values but I don't know where to start.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$15, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$2:E7, $B$2:$B$7), 0)),"")}`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not just copy and sort the copy by *ID* ??

Comment: The index match function will be nested inside a number of IF statements so I do not want to pull through all the values from the original table. Basically If there is a missing value in my second table I want to look this up in the original table and pull through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE with COUNTIF for the k value in the AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/($A$2:$A$7=D2),COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2)))
```

[image]

---

Or to only get the value one by one with Dynamic Array formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=D2),COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, top solution is spot on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 you can simply use `=SORT(A2:B7,1)` in cell `D2` which will automatically create a `Spill Range` with your sorted table

---

[image]